# How to automatically resize to content a Window with an Expander control?

Tags: wpf, window-resize, expander, sizetocontent

I'm trying to figure out how to resize the `Window` of my application after an `Expander` control has been expanded or collapsed. It must grow or shrink. All the cases I've seen before on the StackOverflow suggest to set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`. Is it a right workflow or should I change the size manually?

The application is consist of the `MainWindow` with an `Expander`-based user control in a `StackPanel`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppBlend.MainWindow"                                 
        Title="MainWindow" Width="517" Height="298"
        SizeToContent="Manual" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">    
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UCForm/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is my `UserControl`:

```xml
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfAppBlend.UCForm"
                 d:DesignWidth="500" d:DesignHeight="320" 
                 Width="500" Height="320">
        <Grid>
           <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Header="Bookmarks"
                     Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
                     Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock>
                        Some text here...
                    </TextBlock>
            </Expander> 
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

In my `UserControl` code-behind I have two empty event handlers:

```cs
public partial class UCForm : UserControl
{
    private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        // How to get the instance of the Main Window here
        // to change it's Height?
    }    
    private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        // How to get the instance of the Main Window here
        // to change it's Height?    
    }
}
```

And my `MainWindow` class looks as follows:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }    
    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e){                        
    }
}
```

This is what I've got:

[image]

Setting `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` doesn't work for me.
Expander expands but window size doesn't change.

**UPDATED**: The problem is solved now. The issue was at fixed height. So if you want to make `SizeToContent` to do all dirty work, — you should **NEVER NEVER NEVER** specify the `Height` of your UserControl (only Width) in the case of `ExpandDirection="Down"`. When you specify a fixed Height of the UserControl you must to handle the size change by yourself within an `Expanded()` and `Collapsed()` handlers of your UserControl class. My application layout is fine now:

[image]

Comment: I think this post is too long but I don't know how to use a *spoiler* tag to hide the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` option so that the `Window` automatically resizes to fit exactly its content.

**However**, to make it work properly, you need to remove the `Width="500" Height="320"` properties from your `UCForm` user control, as they give the control (and thus the window content) a fixed height. Your `Window` will then resize as the `UserControl` resizes.

---

As a side note:

```cs
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    // How to get the instance of the Main Window here
    // to change it's Height?
}
```

You almost NEVER want to get the instance of `MainWindow` and resize it from here. The key principle here is *decoupling*: make your `UCForm` re-usable by *not* forcing it to be used inside a `MainWindow`. What if one day you want to use your control somewhere else (another window, another app, or even outside WPF)?

Comment: Thank you man! You had helped me a lot. If you don't mind I'll edit my question to specifiy what was the issue in the `updated` section. Hope it will helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size of UserControl by your own, here some approximate code for the handlers:

```cs
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Getting current position of the Expander Control
    Point exdCtrlPos = ((Expander)sender).TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this);
    // Y + Height of the Expander Control - Height of the UCForm Control
    double delta = (exdCtrlPos.Y + ((Expander)sender).ActualHeight) - Height;
    // Increasing the height of the UCForm by delta
    Height += delta;
}

private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Some code here
    // Decreasing the height of the UCForm by delta
    Height -= delta;
}
```